# How to run Junit test classes in a particular order in Maven without creating suits?

Tags: maven, junit

Is there a quicker way to order the execution of test classes in maven without creating suits?

Comment: Why do you need to order the test executions?

Comment: Because, the test cases are designed in such a way that if the first test case fails, then there is no need to execute the succeeding test cases (If we arrange them in increasing order of coverage). And the workflow that we are testing is a linear one. If we execute the broader test case first, then finding the point of failure will be a bit more time-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven Surfire plugin allows you to specify some order by setting the runOrder element: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <groups>${testcase.groups}</groups>
                <runOrder>reversealphabetical</runOrder>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

To order the methods within a class Junit comes with a [FixMethodOrder](http://junit.org/apidocs/index.html?org/junit/FixMethodOrder.html) annotation. However I had to warn against doing such things. Unit tests should be independent and not require state from the previous test to work.

The class order however requires a [suite](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html), however this is also annotation based and so very small.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestA.class, TestB.class})
public class TestSuite {
}

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestA {
    @Test
    public void testA1() {
        System.out.println("testA1");
    }

    @Test
    public void testA2() {
        System.out.println("testA2");
    }
}

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestB {
    @Test
    public void testB1() {
        System.out.println("testB1");
    }

    @Test
    public void testB2() {
        System.out.println("testB2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to re-order the method execution, I just want to define the sequence in which the test classes are picked up.